# Como ler a chave {1x2} JSON JQuery

Tags: html, jquery, json

Senhores, desculpem a ignorância mas como posso ler uma chave JSON que se inicia em número, exemplo:

```
"1x2": {
     "outright": false,
     "interwetten": {
          "odds": {
                "1": 6.4,
                "2": 1.55,
                "X": 3.95
           },
           "bookmaker": true,
           "exchange": false,
           "name": "Interwetten"
      },
      "bwin": {
          "odds": {
                "1": 6.5,
                "2": 1.5,
                "X": 3.8
          },
           "bookmaker": true,
           "exchange": false,
           "name": "bwin"
},
.....
```

Estou fazendo a leitura da seguinte forma:

```
$.getJSON("MEUJSON", function(retorno){ 
.each(retorno, function (i) {
     // console.log(retorno);
     var data = retorno[i].event.start_time;
     $('.tabela').append(retorno[i].event.away);
     $.each(retorno[i].sites, function(a) {
         //AQUI SERIA A LEITURA DA CHAVE
         console.log(retorno[i].sites[a].\`1x2`\);
     })
})
})
```

Obrigado desde já!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode acessalo desta forma

```js
var meuObj = {"1x2": {
     "outright": false,
     "interwetten": {
          "odds": {
                "1": 6.4,
                "2": 1.55,
                "X": 3.95
           },
           "bookmaker": true,
           "exchange": false,
           "name": "Interwetten"
      },
      "bwin": {
          "odds": {
                "1": 6.5,
                "2": 1.5,
                "X": 3.8
          },
           "bookmaker": true,
           "exchange": false,
           "name": "bwin"
    }
}

var valor1x2 = meuObj["1x2"];
```

Caso seje um array de objetos, tera que acessar o objeto primeiro, para poder acessar seus valores.

> Apenas uma observação na leitura

O `.each` do jquery, alem de entregar os indices, tmb te entrega o elemento iterado no memento do loop.

```js
$.getJSON("MEUJSON", function(retorno){ 
.each(retorno, function (i, ele) {
     // console.log(retorno);
     var data = ele.event.start_time;
     $('.tabela').append(ele.event.away);
     $.each(ele.sites, function(a, site) {
         //AQUI SERIA A LEITURA DA CHAVE
         console.log(site['1x2']);
     })
   })
})
```

Com isso é dispensavel chamar toda vez o objeto raiz e ir decendo os nivel de acordo na hierarquia, como no caso `retorno[i].sites[a]['1x2']` ficou apenas `site['1x2']`, pois o array de sites já esta sendo iterado

Comment: Entendi, no caso meu JSON ele tem outras chaves, e esta dentro de um $.each, estou fazendo assim: 
$.getJSON("MEUJSON", function(retorno){
  $.each(retorno, function (i) {
    // console.log(retorno);
    var data = retorno[i].event.start_time;
    $('.tabela').append(retorno[i].event.away);
    $.each(retorno[i].sites, function(a) {
      //AQUI SERIA A LEITURA DA CHAVE
      console.log(retorno[i].sites[a].\`1x2`\);
      
    })
  })
})

Comment: Tente dessa forma ```console.log(retorno[i].sites[a]['1x2']``` substituindo essa parte ```retorno[i].sites[a].`1x2``` A diferença é que você nãi fazer o acesso com o **.** e sim com os colchetes **[]**

Comment: Bom dia, tentei e não rolou, ele me retorna ->  undefined.

Comment: Bom dia, então é porque dentro do objeto ```retorno[i].sites[a]``` não existe nenhuma chave direta chama '1x2', se você puder mandar a estrututra completa do json, pelo menos esta parte do acesso ao ```site```, pois acho que este objeto não esta diretamente em site. Se puder mandar a estrutura completa de site, ficará mais facil de ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Essa chave é uma String, entao pode usar como base um dos exemplos abaixo:

```
//Usando jquery json parser
var obj = $.parseJSON('{"name": "", "skills": "", "jobtitel": "Entwickler", "res_linkedin": "GwebSearch"}');
alert(obj['jobtitel']);

//Usando javasript json parser
var t = JSON.parse('{"name": "", "skills": "", "jobtitel": "Entwickler", "res_linkedin": "GwebSearch"}');
alert(t['jobtitel'])
```